# Google Directions arrows or gradient

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm creating a bicycle application/service that generates a route for the user using some parameters. So for example i have 4 points (start_point,stop1,stop2 and stop3) Now the directions api calculates a route from start_point to start_point and uses the stops as waypoints. So you get: start, stop1, stop2, stop3,, start.
I have these settings for my directions:

```
renderArray[i] = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            renderArray[i].setMap(map);
            renderArray[i].setOptions({
                    drawingControl: true,
                polylineOptions: {
                    strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
                    strokeOpacity: strokeOpacity,
                    strokeColor: lineColour

                },
                markerOptions:{
                    visible: false
                }
            });
```

The lineColour is a var set up in the beginning of my script to #550000. Now you'll get something like this: [map-example](https://www.google.be/maps/dir/Syosset/New+York+City,+New+York,+Verenigde+Staten/40.6472555,-73.9585364/Freeport/West+Babylon/Syosset,+NY,+Verenigde+Staten/@40.7438791,-73.8043991,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m33!4m32!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2823048424f79:0xd664337ce3794078!2m2!1d-73.502068!2d40.8262101!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62!2m2!1d-73.9780035!2d40.7056308!1m0!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c27b862831ebd5:0x85b75ba23c1e3915!2m2!1d-73.5831835!2d40.6576022!1m5!1m1!1s0x89e82cb1e7028397:0x911f3688036c8474!2m2!1d-73.354287!2d40.718155!1m5!1m1!1s0x89c2823048424f79:0xd664337ce3794078!2m2!1d-73.502068!2d40.8262101!3e1)

A colored line from point to point. But then without more information, so i wan't it to be clear for the user, in what direction they should go. Can someone help me with this?
I thought about setting the strokeColor to a gradient so that it will be devided in 4 colours, but i don't know how to set it to a gradient. My other (maybe better and more logic) option is to add arrows that indicates where to travel to.

More info:
My points are in an array(5 points = start, 3 stops, start)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a [`IconSequence`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#IconSequence),

example:

```
icons:[{repeat:'50px',icon:{path:google.maps.SymbolPath.FORWARD_CLOSED_ARROW}}]
```

add this to the `polylineOptions`